# Preprocessor directive (define) not found by compiler

Tags: c++, preprocessor-directive

I am developing a library where the size of some variables depends on a #define and some #define which are created depending on the value of other #define.

e.g.

```
int variable1[SIZE_USER]
#if SIZE_USER>3
  #define CONDITION 1
#else
  #define CONDITION 0
#endif
```

The idea is that when a user wants to work with the library they create there own header file with all the preprocessor directives (#define) that are needed and uses this file in the same directory where there "main.cpp" file is and not inside the library source files.

The problem is that when I include the configuration file (which has all the #define's)  in the same directory where all my header files of the library are I do not have problems.

i.e.

```
#include <config.h>
//My Library Code...
```

But if I declare the configuration header file outside the source files of my Library the compiler doesn't find the #define's that were declared in the "main.cpp" file.

i.e.

```
#include<config.h>
#include<myLibrary.h>
//User code...
```

Is there something obvious I am missing on how the compiler is working?

Comment: How and where `SIZE_USER` is created?

Comment: it is created in an external header file e.g. "config.h"

Comment: When the library source files are compiled, the compiler needs to have access to the user header file. So either this header file has to be located where the source code is, or the path has to be passed when compiling, e.g. by passing it to the compiler using the `-I` flag. Is the library compiled at the same time as the user program which consumes it?

Comment: precompiled headers?

Comment: Use angle brackets only for .h files provided by the compiler.  When you make it difficult for the compiler to find a .h file then there is always a risk that the compiler finds *another* config.h file.  Sounds like that is exactly what happened, "config.h" is far too common a filename.  It is diagnosable, but you have to tell us what kind of compiler you use to get the most usable answer.

Comment: Do you mean that the compiler isn't finding your header, or isn't defining the variables (but sees your header?)  You can easily test by putting an #error into your header and seeing if you get it.  If not, it's not finding your header.  Check your include path, because it may be finding another header with the same name.  Also, use "" for your own (non system-library) includes, as most compilers have different search paths for <> and "", and some swallow warnings in system headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define SIZE_USER 4

int variable1[SIZE_USER]
#if SIZE_USER > 3
  #define CONDITION 1
#else
  #define CONDITION 0
#endif
```

First problem is missing spaces in the #if directive.

```
#include "myLibrary.h"
```

Second problem: use "" for your included headers and spaces matter.